# scipy odeint: excess work done on this call depending on initial values even with analytically solvable ODE

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to solve a differential equation in the form:
dx/dt = funct(x)
using scipy odeint.

However, for some initial values, I get a "ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call", even if the ODE itself seems to be solvable analytically. Why does the numerical ODE solver give me a warning, and how can I make it work instead of jumping to x > 3e^7?

Here is a minimal (non) working example:

```
x0 =0.49 # works, but changing to 0.51 gives the ODEint warning
t = np.linspace(0,10,100)
def funct(x,t):
    return 2*x**2-x
x, out = integrate.odeint(funct, x0, t, full_output = 1)
plt.plot(t,x)
```

I am not too good at math, but I think the analytical answer should be:
x = 1/(2 + C * exp(t))
with C being any constant.

If so, I think using initial value of x0=0.51 should also be numerically solvable because C exists (C = -0.04).

The closest question I could find was:
[scipy odeint: excess work done on this call and very sensitive to initial value](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36117/scipy-odeint-excess-work-done-on-this-call-and-very-sensitive-to-initial-value)
However, the ODE in the previous question blows up analytically, whereas mine does not.

Edit:
My real function and x are vectors and matrices about networks, not an analytically solvable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, for $x>0.5$, your example ODE yields $dx/dt>0$ and thus $x$ will increase and its time derivative as well. Therefore the solution diverges, even faster than a simple exponential after some time (when $x^2 \gg x$). If you start at $x=0.5$, the solution is a constant. For $x<0.5$, the solution converges to 0.

In the case of a divergence, the error estimate that is used to dynamically adapt the time step will require time steps smaller and smaller, and at one point lower than $10^{-15}$, or at least such that $t+dt=t$ at machine precision. The solver then assumes that there is no point in trying to pursue the integration and notifies you. That behaviour is absolutely normal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was super helpful as I didn't realize that analytically solvable ODEs might still not be "solvable" with ODEint. I plotted the results of ODEint between 0<t<4, 0<x<20, and confirmed it increases in a super-exponential way as expected from the analytical solution.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise in the influence of the initial value, the ODE $\dot x=2x^2-x$ is Bernoulli. With $u=x^{-1}$ one gets
$$
\dot u=-x^{-2}\dot x=u-2\implies u=2+(u_0-2)e^t\implies x=\frac{x_0}{2x_0+(1-2x_0)e^t}.
$$
The denominator has a pole for $x_0>\frac12$ at $t_{pole}=\ln(\frac{x_0}{x_0-\frac12})$. For $x_0=0.51$ this gives $t_{pole}=\ln(51)=3.931825...$ This singularity provides an insurmountable obstacle for the integrator. There could be more informative error messages, but `odeint` just reports the failure of the step-size controller.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Bernoulli ODEs so I appreciate your detailed comment. I also should have checked the existence of a pole at t = ln(51). 

For now, I will ignore the error, but if I find the running time is too long, I will follow your suggestions to use solve_ivp here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072604/how-to-get-scipy-integrate-odeint-to-stop-when-path-is-closed. Thanks!